# How to delete an existing embed in DiscordJS (v12)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on a small private Discord bot (mainly for learning)
I've been working on a feature where the bot sends a message, the user sends a response and the bot will delete the initial embed and follow up with another embed. 
(creating a chain of embedded messages to collect user input and build a final result from it)

Thus far this is what my code consists of

```
const wait = 30000;
    let count;

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#9EFF9A')
        .setTitle('Question?')
        .setDescription('');

    message.channel.send(embed);
    message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id,
        { max: 1, time: `${wait}` }).then(collected => {
        message.delete(embed);
        count = collected.first().content;
            console.log(count);
    }).catch(() => {
        message.delete(embed);
        return message.reply('No reply after ' + `${wait / 1000}` + ' seconds, operation canceled.').then(m => {
            m.delete({ timeout: 15000 });
        });
    });
```

I have tried various iterations of `message.delete();` with no useful results, the bot usually ends up deleting the commanding message sent by the user to start the embed chain.
I got a suggestion from a friend that I also ended up seeing online a few times which was the following:

```
.then(() => {
message.delete()
})
```

I can't come up with any way to implement this into my current code.
Is there something I am misunderstanding? I am very new to DiscordJS and Javascript and my friend did mention that .then() statements can get pretty tricky

I appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very close to achieving what you want, except you are attempting to delete the `Embed` object that you created instead of the `Message` object of the embed. Here's a slight tweak that will achieve what you need:

```
const wait = 30000;
let count;

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#9EFF9A')
    .setTitle('Question?')
    .setDescription('');

message.channel.send(embed).then(embedMessage => {
    embedMessage.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id,
    { max: 1, time: wait }).then(collected => {
        embedMessage.delete();
        count = collected.first().content;
        console.log(count);
    }).catch(() => {
        embedMessage.delete();
        return message.reply('No reply after ' + (wait / 1000) + ' seconds, operation canceled.').then(m => {
            m.delete({ timeout: 15000 });
        });
    });
})
```

The secret here is using `.then()` on the method that sends the embed. This allows you to obtain the actual `Message` object of the embed that was sent, which you can then interact with. Now that you have the `Message` object for your embed, you can directly interact with the message using its methods, such as `delete()` and `edit()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.then(() => {
   message.delete()
})
```

Is not working because you never passed in the message as a parameter, therefor your embed does not exist in the context of `.then()`

You can try using `.then()` or `await` to delete a send message.

**then Method**

```
// const embed = ...
message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {
   msg.delete();
});
```

**Await Method**

```
// Make sure you're in an async function
//const embed = ...
const msg = await message.channel.send(msg);
msg.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not to familiar with discordjs but from what I understand you create a message with the bot under the variable "message" which has the properties seen here:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message

Then you use that message to send an embed to the message's channel. The embed ask's a question and you then await for ensuing messages. You then want to take the first response and put it into the count variable. Then you want to delete the original embed. If this is all true I would suggest deleting the original message that houses the embed itself like so:

```
message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id,
    { max: 1, time: `${wait}` }).then(collected => {
    message.delete();
    count = collected.first().content;
        console.log(count);
})
```

Or try this but I don't think this method will work:

```
message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id,
    { max: 1, time: `${wait}` }).then(collected => {
    embed.delete();
    count = collected.first().content;
        console.log(count);
})
```

I would check out these two pages of documentation:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=delete
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageEmbed

Welcome to Stack Overflow tell me if one of these worked.

Comment: The `message` object actually doesn't contain the message with the embed in it. The `message` object is a message the user sent, such as a command, and the embed is what the bot sent in response to that message. The `embed` object is also not the message that contains the embed, it is essentially just a JSON structure that represents the embed's structure itself (i.e. something like `{description: "Desc", fields: [], "title": "Title"}`). The easiest way to obtain the message containing the embed is by using `.then()` or `await` on the `message.channel.send(embed)` statement.